# How to read a text file from the root folder and display it in div?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have a complicated html page. I want to read a text file and display its content into a div on Page load. I can use javascript if needed. Pl. help.

Comment: Where is this text file?  The root folder of what machine; the client computer where the web browser is running?

Comment: When you say "from the root folder" do you mean the *Web* root, or the root of the actual web server filesystem?  Because allowing the latter is extremely dangerous.  Also, what is "complicated" about this? Why would `<iframe src="/mytextfile.txt">` not be sufficient? More details of the problem will get you better answers.

Answer (score 2):

Your file is on your server in California. JavaScript is running on the user's computer in Tokyo.

How is the user's computer supposed to read content from your server? It cannot. You need to use a server-side language (PHP, Ruby, Perl, ASP, etc.) on your server to dynamically compose the HTML to send to the user.

What server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the jQuery $.ajax() method to load your text file.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '<enter text file url here>',
  dataType: "text",
  success: function(data){
     //load content to div
     $("#<divId>").html(data);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it on the server?

```
<?php
echo '<div>' . file_get_contents('yourtextfile.txt') . '</div>';
?>
```

Comment: edited to make it clearer that yes, it's php.  :P  As you pointed out, Jango's not going to do it in JS, is he?

Answer (score 0):

why couldn't he use jQuery or something to do an AJAX request? if the text file is on the server it should work alight.

```
$(function(){
    $('div').load('path_to/textfile.txt', function(){
        alert('data was loaded');
    });
});
```